# How do nonlinear phenomena arise from linear theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, schroedinger-equation, maxwell-equations, non-linear-systems

How is it possible that linear theories, for example maxwells equations or the schroedinger equation, produce nonlinear physics?

Comment: I actually think it is the other way around. Linear equations follow as special cases from nonlinear equations. Take Einstein's field equations of G.R., these are a coupled set of 10, nonlinear, hyperbolic PDEs. You want Electromagnetism, stick in $F_{ab}$, you want fluid dynamics, $T_{ab} = (\mu + p) u_{a} u_{b} + p g_{ab}$. The linear theories follow from geometric simplifications to these equations.

Comment: How do you define "nonlinear physics"?

Comment: Are you assuming that, e.g., the permeability of real materials is constant?

Comment: one of the most interesting appearance of nonlinear behavior is the one that emerges from a linear differential equation but with a free surface boundary condition, such as at the interface of air and water.

Comment: Can you give an example of nonlinearity you'd like explained? Right now this looks like a list question.

Comment: It is not correct that the Maxwell equations are linear, since the constitutive equations (dependencies $D= D(E,B)$, $H = H(E,B)$ and $J=J(E,B))$ are nonlinear, in general, see J. D. Jackson, Classical electrodynamics (1999). For waves in vacuum, the constitutive equations are linear, so that the whole system is also linear.

Comment: Well, it often happens that it is the opposite. The complete theory is non-linear and the linear theory is just some useful "free theory version" on top of which we can add corrections perturbatively to approximate the complete theory. Example: in QFT, interacting fields obey non-linear equations which are intractable to be exactly solved by several technical issues (products of distributions, etc). The free theory is linear and then we resort to perturbation theory to connect the two and say something about the complete theory using the free one.

Comment: The answer is either "linear equations don't display nonlinear behavior" or "you are using the word *linear* in two different ways in your question," depending on exactly what you mean by "nonlinear phenomena."

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting non-linear results from linear equations is to have interactions that are spread over time and/or space. This will require integration of the linear interaction, which will result in non-linear behavior. For example, if you integrate $dx/dt = kx$, you get $x=\exp(kt)$, which is clearly non-linear in both $k$ and $t$.

In another example, take Hooke's law $F = -k x$ (where $F$ is the force, $k$ is the spring constant, and $x$ is the displacement from equilibrium). You can generalize it to continuous media with stress = constant $\times$ strain. This is clearly linear. However, if you calculate the deflection of a beam of a material of uniform composition and cross-section, you get non-linear effects, for example with deflection with a given force depending non-linearly on the length of the beam. This is because deformation at one point in the beam influences deformation at another point as static equilibrium is achieved. This coupling between different parts of the beam causes the non-linear term to arise.

Comment: How does this work quantum mechanically? If the schroedinger equation is linear and the underlying mathematics is linear, where is there room for nonlinear phenomena?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but same thing. Every location in space influences the others as it is a pde. For example, eigenvalues of hamiltonian for the hydrogen atom are spaced as n squared. Probability of tunneling is non linear in potential width, etc...

Comment: If quantum mechanics can be "built up" do describe very complex systems, how do we get things like nonlinearity of the navier stokes equation or nonlinear optics. For situations where nonlinearity from GR is negligible, then shouldn't all phenomena be linear?

Comment: For navier stokes, look at its derivation, you will see how the non linear terms arise. It's again a distributed system where things happening at one location can influence what happens at another.

Comment: For non linear optics, look at the second harmonic generation article on Wikipedia. It has a nice explanation.

Comment: @ZacharyCarter what if, in the Schrodinger equation,  the potential is proportional to $\vert \psi\vert^2$?